# Liferay service builder error on windows

Tags: liferay, liferay-service-builder

I am new to Liferay. While building service, i am getting following error.
liferay version :liferay-portal-6.2-ce-ga6
plugin sdk:liferay-plugins-sdk-7.0

Please help.

below is the error:

[Console output redirected to file:D:\LDS\lds\DeveloperStudio\workspace.metadata.plugins\com.liferay.ide.sdk.core\sdk.log]
Buildfile: D:\LDS\lds\lsdk\portlets\AAA-portlet\build.xml
build-service:
      [jar] Building MANIFEST-only jar: D:\LDS\lds\lsdk\portlets\AAA-portlet\service-builder-classpath.jar
   [delete] Deleting: D:\LDS\lds\lsdk\portlets\AAA-portlet\service-builder-classpath.jar.manifest
   [delete] Deleting: D:\LDS\lds\lsdk\portlets\AAA-portlet\service-builder-classpath.jar
     [echo] Building Foo
     [echo] Writing D:\LDS\lds\lsdk\portlets\AAA-portlet\docroot\WEB-INF\src\service.properties
    [javac] Compiling 18 source files to D:\LDS\lds\lsdk\portlets\AAA-portlet\docroot\WEB-INF\service-classes
    [javac] D:\LDS\lds\lsdk\portlets\AAA-portlet\docroot\WEB-INF\service\z\exception\NoSuchFooException.java:19: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac] import com.liferay.portal.kernel.exception.NoSuchModelException;
    [javac]                                           ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class NoSuchModelException
    [javac]   location: package com.liferay.portal.kernel.exception
    [javac] D:\LDS\lds\lsdk\portlets\AAA-portlet\docroot\WEB-INF\service\z\exception\NoSuchFooException.java:25: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac] public class NoSuchFooException extends NoSuchModelException {
    [javac]                                         ^
    [javac]   symbol: class NoSuchModelException
    [javac] D:\LDS\lds\lsdk\portlets\AAA-portlet\docroot\WEB-INF\service\z\model\Foo.java:19: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac] import com.liferay.portal.kernel.annotation.ImplementationClassName;
    [javac]                                            ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class ImplementationClassName
    [javac]   location: package com.liferay.portal.kernel.annotation
    [javac] D:\LDS\lds\lsdk\portlets\AAA-portlet\docroot\WEB-INF\service\z\model\Foo.java:20: error: package com.liferay.portal.kernel.model does not exist
    [javac] import com.liferay.portal.kernel.model.PersistedModel;
    [javac]                                       ^
    [javac] D:\LDS\lds\lsdk\portlets\AAA-portlet\docroot\WEB-INF\service\z\model\FooModel.java:19: error: package com.liferay.expando.kernel.model does not exist
    [javac] import com.liferay.expando.kernel.model.ExpandoBridge;
    [javac]                                        ^
    [javac] D:\LDS\lds\lsdk\portlets\AAA-portlet\docroot\WEB-INF\service\z\model\FooModel.java:22: error: package com.liferay.portal.kernel.model does not exist
    [javac] import com.liferay.portal.kernel.model.BaseModel;
    [javac]                                       ^
    [javac] D:\LDS\lds\lsdk\portlets\AAA-portlet\docroot\WEB-INF\service\z\model\FooModel.java:23: error: package com.liferay.portal.kernel.model does not exist
    [javac] import com.liferay.portal.kernel.model.CacheModel;
    [javac]                                       ^
    [javac] D:\LDS\lds\lsdk\portlets\AAA-portlet\docroot\WEB-INF\service\z\model\FooModel.java:24: error: package com.liferay.portal.kernel.model does not exist
    [javac] import com.liferay.portal.kernel.model.GroupedModel;
    [javac]                                       ^
    [javac] D:\LDS\lds\lsdk\portlets\AAA-portlet\docroot\WEB-INF\service\z\model\FooModel.java:25: error: package com.liferay.portal.kernel.model does not exist
    [javac] import com.liferay.portal.kernel.model.ShardedModel;
    [javac]                                       ^
    [javac] D:\LDS\lds\lsdk\portlets\AAA-portlet\docroot\WEB-INF\service\z\model\FooModel.java:26: error: package com.liferay.portal.kernel.service does not exist
    [javac] import com.liferay.portal.kernel.service.ServiceContext;
    [javac]                                         ^
    [javac] D:\LDS\lds\lsdk\portlets\AAA-portlet\docroot\WEB-INF\service\z\model\FooModel.java:46: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac] public interface FooModel extends BaseModel, GroupedModel, ShardedModel {
    [javac]                                   ^
    [javac]   symbol: class BaseModel
    [javac] D:\LDS\lds\lsdk\portlets\AAA-portlet\docroot\WEB-INF\service\z\model\FooModel.java:46: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac] public interface FooModel extends BaseModel, GroupedModel, ShardedModel {
    [javac]                                                   ^
    [javac]   symbol: class GroupedModel
    [javac] D:\LDS\lds\lsdk\portlets\AAA-portlet\docroot\WEB-INF\service\z\model\FooModel.java:46: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac] public interface FooModel extends BaseModel, GroupedModel, ShardedModel {
    [javac]                                                                 ^
    [javac]   symbol: class ShardedModel
    [javac] D:\LDS\lds\lsdk\portlets\AAA-portlet\docroot\WEB-INF\service\z\model\Foo.java:34: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac] public interface Foo extends FooModel, PersistedModel {
    [javac]                                        ^
    [javac]   symbol: class PersistedModel
    [javac] D:\LDS\lds\lsdk\portlets\AAA-portlet\docroot\WEB-INF\service\z\model\Foo.java:32: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac] @ImplementationClassName("z.model.impl.FooImpl")
    [javac]  ^
    [javac]   symbol: class ImplementationClassName
    [javac] D:\LDS\lds\lsdk\portlets\AAA-portlet\docroot\WEB-INF\service\z\model\FooModel.java:295: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]     public ExpandoBridge getExpandoBridge();
    [javac]            ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class ExpandoBridge
    [javac]   location: interface FooModel
    [javac] D:\LDS\lds\lsdk\portlets\AAA-portlet\docroot\WEB-INF\service\z\model\FooModel.java:298: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]     public void setExpandoBridgeAttributes(BaseModel baseModel);
    [javac]                                            ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class BaseModel
    [javac]   location: interface FooModel
    [javac] D:\LDS\lds\lsdk\portlets\AAA-portlet\docroot\WEB-INF\service\z\model\FooModel.java:301: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]     public void setExpandoBridgeAttributes(ExpandoBridge expandoBridge);
    [javac]                                            ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class ExpandoBridge
    [javac]   location: interface FooModel
    [javac] D:\LDS\lds\lsdk\portlets\AAA-portlet\docroot\WEB-INF\service\z\model\FooModel.java:304: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]     public void setExpandoBridgeAttributes(ServiceContext serviceContext);
    [javac]                                            ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class ServiceContext
    [javac]   location: interface FooModel
    [javac] D:\LDS\lds\lsdk\portlets\AAA-portlet\docroot\WEB-INF\service\z\model\FooModel.java:316: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]     public CacheModel toCacheModel();
    [javac]            ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class CacheModel
    [javac]   location: interface FooModel
    [javac] D:\LDS\lds\lsdk\portlets\AAA-portlet\docroot\WEB-INF\service\z\model\FooClp.java:21: error: package com.liferay.portal.kernel.model does not exist
    [javac] import com.liferay.portal.kernel.model.BaseModel;
    [javac]                                       ^
    [javac] D:\LDS\lds\lsdk\portlets\AAA-portlet\docroot\WEB-INF\service\z\model\FooClp.java:22: error: package com.liferay.portal.kernel.model does not exist
    [javac] import com.liferay.portal.kernel.model.User;
    [javac]                                       ^
    [javac] D:\LDS\lds\lsdk\portlets\AAA-portlet\docroot\WEB-INF\service\z\model\FooClp.java:23: error: package com.liferay.portal.kernel.model.impl does not exist
    [javac] import com.liferay.portal.kernel.model.impl.BaseModelImpl;
    [javac]                                            ^
    [javac] D:\LDS\lds\lsdk\portlets\AAA-portlet\docroot\WEB-INF\service\z\model\FooClp.java:24: error: package com.liferay.portal.kernel.service does not exist
    [javac] import com.liferay.portal.kernel.service.UserLocalServiceUtil;
    [javac]                                         ^
    [javac] D:\LDS\lds\lsdk\portlets\AAA-portlet\docroot\WEB-INF\service\z\model\FooClp.java:45: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac] public class FooClp extends BaseModelImpl implements Foo {
    [javac]                             ^
    [javac]   symbol: class BaseModelImpl
    [javac] D:\LDS\lds\lsdk\portlets\AAA-portlet\docroot\WEB-INF\service\z\model\FooClp.java:477: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]     public BaseModel getFooRemoteModel() {
    [javac]            ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class BaseModel
    [javac]   location: class FooClp
    [javac] D:\LDS\lds\lsdk\portlets\AAA-portlet\docroot\WEB-INF\service\z\model\FooClp.java:481: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]     public void setFooRemoteModel(BaseModel fooRemoteModel) {
    [javac]                                   ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class BaseModel
    [javac]   location: class FooClp
    [javac] D:\LDS\lds\lsdk\portlets\AAA-portlet\docroot\WEB-INF\service\z\model\FooClp.java:723: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]     private BaseModel _fooRemoteModel;
    [javac]             ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class BaseModel
    [javac]   location: class FooClp
    [javac] D:\LDS\lds\lsdk\portlets\AAA-portlet\docroot\WEB-INF\service\z\model\FooWrapper.java:19: error: package com.liferay.expando.kernel.model does not exist
    [javac] import com.liferay.expando.kernel.model.ExpandoBridge;
    [javac]                                        ^
    [javac] D:\LDS\lds\lsdk\portlets\AAA-portlet\docroot\WEB-INF\service\z\model\FooWrapper.java:21: error: package com.liferay.portal.kernel.model does not exist
    [javac] import com.liferay.portal.kernel.model.ModelWrapper;
    [javac]                                       ^
    [javac] D:\LDS\lds\lsdk\portlets\AAA-portlet\docroot\WEB-INF\service\z\model\FooWrapper.java:22: error: package com.liferay.portal.kernel.service does not exist
    [javac] import com.liferay.portal.kernel.service.ServiceContext;
    [javac]                                         ^
    [javac] D:\LDS\lds\lsdk\portlets\AAA-portlet\docroot\WEB-INF\service\z\model\FooWrapper.java:41: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac] public class FooWrapper implements Foo, ModelWrapper {
    [javac]                                         ^
    [javac]   symbol: class ModelWrapper
    [javac] D:\LDS\lds\lsdk\portlets\AAA-portlet\docroot\WEB-INF\service\z\model\FooWrapper.java:182: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]     public ExpandoBridge getExpandoBridge() {
    [javac]            ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class ExpandoBridge
    [javac]   location: class FooWrapper
    [javac] D:\LDS\lds\lsdk\portlets\AAA-portlet\docroot\WEB-INF\service\z\model\FooWrapper.java:373: error: package com.liferay.portal.kernel.model does not exist
    [javac]         com.liferay.portal.kernel.model.BaseModel baseModel) {
    [javac]                                        ^
    [javac] D:\LDS\lds\lsdk\portlets\AAA-portlet\docroot\WEB-INF\service\z\model\FooWrapper.java:378: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]     public void setExpandoBridgeAttributes(ExpandoBridge expandoBridge) {
    [javac]                                            ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class ExpandoBridge
    [javac]   location: class FooWrapper
    [javac] D:\LDS\lds\lsdk\portlets\AAA-portlet\docroot\WEB-INF\service\z\model\FooWrapper.java:383: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]     public void setExpandoBridgeAttributes(ServiceContext serviceContext) {
    [javac]                                            ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class ServiceContext
    [javac]   location: class FooWrapper
    [javac] D:\LDS\lds\lsdk\portlets\AAA-portlet\docroot\WEB-INF\service\z\model\FooWrapper.java:518: error: package com.liferay.portal.kernel.model does not exist
    [javac]     public com.liferay.portal.kernel.model.CacheModel toCacheModel() {
    [javac]                                           ^
    [javac] D:\LDS\lds\lsdk\portlets\AAA-portlet\docroot\WEB-INF\service\z\service\ClpSerializer.java:23: error: package com.liferay.portal.kernel.model does not exist
    [javac] import com.liferay.portal.kernel.model.BaseModel;
    [javac]                                       ^
    [javac] D:\LDS\lds\lsdk\portlets\AAA-portlet\docroot\WEB-INF\service\z\service\ClpSerializer.java:101: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]     public static Object translateInput(BaseModel oldModel) {
    [javac]                                         ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class BaseModel
    [javac]   location: class ClpSerializer
    [javac] D:\LDS\lds\lsdk\portlets\AAA-portlet\docroot\WEB-INF\service\z\service\ClpSerializer.java:125: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]     public static Object translateInputFoo(BaseModel oldModel) {
    [javac]                                            ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class BaseModel
    [javac]   location: class ClpSerializer
    [javac] D:\LDS\lds\lsdk\portlets\AAA-portlet\docroot\WEB-INF\service\z\service\ClpSerializer.java:147: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]     public static Object translateOutput(BaseModel oldModel) {
    [javac]                                          ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class BaseModel
    [javac]   location: class ClpSerializer
    [javac] D:\LDS\lds\lsdk\portlets\AAA-portlet\docroot\WEB-INF\service\z\service\ClpSerializer.java:275: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]     public static Object translateOutputFoo(BaseModel oldModel) {
    [javac]                                             ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class BaseModel
    [javac]   location: class ClpSerializer
    [javac] D:\LDS\lds\lsdk\portlets\AAA-portlet\docroot\WEB-INF\service\z\service\FooLocalService.java:21: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac] import com.liferay.portal.kernel.dao.orm.IndexableActionableDynamicQuery;
    [javac]                                         ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class IndexableActionableDynamicQuery
    [javac]   location: package com.liferay.portal.kernel.dao.orm
    [javac] D:\LDS\lds\lsdk\portlets\AAA-portlet\docroot\WEB-INF\service\z\service\FooLocalService.java:25: error: package com.liferay.portal.kernel.model does not exist
    [javac] import com.liferay.portal.kernel.model.PersistedModel;
    [javac]                                       ^
    [javac] D:\LDS\lds\lsdk\portlets\AAA-portlet\docroot\WEB-INF\service\z\service\FooLocalService.java:28: error: package com.liferay.portal.kernel.service does not exist
    [javac] import com.liferay.portal.kernel.service.BaseLocalService;
    [javac]                                         ^
    [javac] D:\LDS\lds\lsdk\portlets\AAA-portlet\docroot\WEB-INF\service\z\service\FooLocalService.java:29: error: package com.liferay.portal.kernel.service does not exist
    [javac] import com.liferay.portal.kernel.service.InvokableLocalService;
    [javac]                                         ^
    [javac] D:\LDS\lds\lsdk\portlets\AAA-portlet\docroot\WEB-INF\service\z\service\FooLocalService.java:30: error: package com.liferay.portal.kernel.service does not exist
    [javac] import com.liferay.portal.kernel.service.PersistedModelLocalService;
    [javac]                                         ^
    [javac] D:\LDS\lds\lsdk\portlets\AAA-portlet\docroot\WEB-INF\service\z\service\FooLocalService.java:57: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac] public interface FooLocalService extends BaseLocalService, InvokableLocalService,
    [javac]                                          ^
    [javac]   symbol: class BaseLocalService
    [javac] D:\LDS\lds\lsdk\portlets\AAA-portlet\docroot\WEB-INF\service\z\service\FooLocalService.java:57: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac] public interface FooLocalService extends BaseLocalService, InvokableLocalService,
    [javac]                                                            ^
    [javac]   symbol: class InvokableLocalService
    [javac] D:\LDS\lds\lsdk\portlets\AAA-portlet\docroot\WEB-INF\service\z\service\FooLocalService.java:58: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]     PersistedModelLocalService {
    [javac]     ^
    [javac]   symbol: class PersistedModelLocalService
    [javac] D:\LDS\lds\lsdk\portlets\AAA-portlet\docroot\WEB-INF\service\z\service\FooLocalService.java:105: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]     public PersistedModel deletePersistedModel(PersistedModel persistedModel)
    [javac]                                                ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class PersistedModel
    [javac]   location: interface FooLocalService
    [javac] D:\LDS\lds\lsdk\portlets\AAA-portlet\docroot\WEB-INF\service\z\service\FooLocalService.java:105: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]     public PersistedModel deletePersistedModel(PersistedModel persistedModel)
    [javac]            ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class PersistedModel
    [javac]   location: interface FooLocalService
    [javac] D:\LDS\lds\lsdk\portlets\AAA-portlet\docroot\WEB-INF\service\z\service\FooLocalService.java:147: error: type OrderByComparator does not take parameters
    [javac]         int end, OrderByComparator orderByComparator);
    [javac]                                   ^
    [javac] D:\LDS\lds\lsdk\portlets\AAA-portlet\docroot\WEB-INF\service\z\service\FooLocalService.java:206: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]     public IndexableActionableDynamicQuery getIndexableActionableDynamicQuery();
    [javac]            ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class IndexableActionableDynamicQuery
    [javac]   location: interface FooLocalService
    [javac] D:\LDS\lds\lsdk\portlets\AAA-portlet\docroot\WEB-INF\service\z\service\FooLocalService.java:217: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]     public PersistedModel getPersistedModel(Serializable primaryKeyObj)
    [javac]            ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class PersistedModel
    [javac]   location: interface FooLocalService
    [javac] D:\LDS\lds\lsdk\portlets\AAA-portlet\docroot\WEB-INF\service\z\service\FooLocalServiceClp.java:19: error: package com.liferay.portal.kernel.service does not exist
    [javac] import com.liferay.portal.kernel.service.InvokableLocalService;
    [javac]                                         ^
    [javac] D:\LDS\lds\lsdk\portlets\AAA-portlet\docroot\WEB-INF\service\z\service\FooLocalServiceClp.java:27: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]     public FooLocalServiceClp(InvokableLocalService invokableLocalService) {
    [javac]                               ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class InvokableLocalService
    [javac]   location: class FooLocalServiceClp
    [javac] D:\LDS\lds\lsdk\portlets\AAA-portlet\docroot\WEB-INF\service\z\service\FooLocalServiceClp.java:226: error: package com.liferay.portal.kernel.model does not exist
    [javac]         com.liferay.portal.kernel.model.PersistedModel persistedModel)                                                      ^
    [javac] D:\LDS\lds\lsdk\portlets\AAA-portlet\docroot\WEB-INF\service\z\service\FooLocalServiceClp.java:545: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]     public com.liferay.portal.kernel.dao.orm.IndexableActionableDynamicQuery getIndexableActionableDynamicQuery() {
    [javac]                                             ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class IndexableActionableDynamicQuery
    [javac]   location: package com.liferay.portal.kernel.dao.orm
    [javac] D:\LDS\lds\lsdk\portlets\AAA-portlet\docroot\WEB-INF\service\z\service\FooLocalServiceClp.java:591: error: package com.liferay.portal.kernel.model does not exist
    [javac]     public com.liferay.portal.kernel.model.PersistedModel getPersistedModel(
    [javac]                                           ^
    [javac] D:\LDS\lds\lsdk\portlets\AAA-portlet\docroot\WEB-INF\service\z\service\FooLocalServiceClp.java:651: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]     private InvokableLocalService _invokableLocalService;
    [javac]             ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class InvokableLocalService
    [javac]   location: class FooLocalServiceClp
    [javac] D:\LDS\lds\lsdk\portlets\AAA-portlet\docroot\WEB-INF\service\z\service\FooLocalServiceUtil.java:20: error: package com.liferay.portal.kernel.service does not exist
    [javac] import com.liferay.portal.kernel.service.InvokableLocalService;
    [javac]                                         ^
    [javac] D:\LDS\lds\lsdk\portlets\AAA-portlet\docroot\WEB-INF\service\z\service\FooLocalServiceUtil.java:91: error: package com.liferay.portal.kernel.model does not exist
    [javac]         com.liferay.portal.kernel.model.PersistedModel persistedModel)
    [javac]                                        ^
    [javac] D:\LDS\lds\lsdk\portlets\AAA-portlet\docroot\WEB-INF\service\z\service\FooLocalServiceUtil.java:90: error: package com.liferay.portal.kernel.model does not exist
    [javac]     public static com.liferay.portal.kernel.model.PersistedModel deletePersistedModel(
    [javac]                                                  ^
    [javac] D:\LDS\lds\lsdk\portlets\AAA-portlet\docroot\WEB-INF\service\z\service\FooLocalServiceUtil.java:145: error: type OrderByComparator does not take parameters
    [javac]         com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.OrderByComparator orderByComparator) {
    [javac]                                                         ^
    [javac] D:\LDS\lds\lsdk\portlets\AAA-portlet\docroot\WEB-INF\service\z\service\FooLocalServiceUtil.java:218: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]     public static com.liferay.portal.kernel.dao.orm.IndexableActionableDynamicQuery getIndexableActionableDynamicQuery() {
    [javac]                                                    ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class IndexableActionableDynamicQuery
    [javac]   location: package com.liferay.portal.kernel.dao.orm
    [javac] D:\LDS\lds\lsdk\portlets\AAA-portlet\docroot\WEB-INF\service\z\service\FooLocalServiceUtil.java:231: error: package com.liferay.portal.kernel.model does not exist
    [javac]     public static com.liferay.portal.kernel.model.PersistedModel getPersistedModel(
    [javac]                                                  ^
    [javac] D:\LDS\lds\lsdk\portlets\AAA-portlet\docroot\WEB-INF\service\z\service\FooLocalServiceWrapper.java:19: error: package com.liferay.portal.kernel.service does not exist
    [javac] import com.liferay.portal.kernel.service.ServiceWrapper;
    [javac]                                         ^
    [javac] D:\LDS\lds\lsdk\portlets\AAA-portlet\docroot\WEB-INF\service\z\service\FooLocalServiceWrapper.java:30: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]     ServiceWrapper {
    [javac]     ^
    [javac]   symbol: class ServiceWrapper
    [javac] D:\LDS\lds\lsdk\portlets\AAA-portlet\docroot\WEB-INF\service\z\service\FooLocalServiceWrapper.java:86: error: package com.liferay.portal.kernel.model does not exist
    [javac]         com.liferay.portal.kernel.model.PersistedModel persistedModel)
    [javac]                                        ^
    [javac] D:\LDS\lds\lsdk\portlets\AAA-portlet\docroot\WEB-INF\service\z\service\FooLocalServiceWrapper.java:85: error: package com.liferay.portal.kernel.model does not exist
    [javac]     public com.liferay.portal.kernel.model.PersistedModel deletePersistedModel(
    [javac]                                           ^
    [javac] D:\LDS\lds\lsdk\portlets\AAA-portlet\docroot\WEB-INF\service\z\service\FooLocalServiceWrapper.java:144: error: type OrderByComparator does not take parameters
    [javac]         com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.OrderByComparator orderByComparator) {
    [javac]                                                         ^
    [javac] D:\LDS\lds\lsdk\portlets\AAA-portlet\docroot\WEB-INF\service\z\service\FooLocalServiceWrapper.java:225: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]     public com.liferay.portal.kernel.dao.orm.IndexableActionableDynamicQuery getIndexableActionableDynamicQuery() {
    [javac]                                             ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class IndexableActionableDynamicQuery
    [javac]   location: package com.liferay.portal.kernel.dao.orm
    [javac] D:\LDS\lds\lsdk\portlets\AAA-portlet\docroot\WEB-INF\service\z\service\FooLocalServiceWrapper.java:240: error: package com.liferay.portal.kernel.model does not exist
    [javac]     public com.liferay.portal.kernel.model.PersistedModel getPersistedModel(
    [javac]                                           ^
    [javac] D:\LDS\lds\lsdk\portlets\AAA-portlet\docroot\WEB-INF\service\z\service\FooService.java:22: error: package com.liferay.portal.kernel.security.access.control does not exist
    [javac] import com.liferay.portal.kernel.security.access.control.AccessControlled;
    [javac]                                                         ^
    [javac] D:\LDS\lds\lsdk\portlets\AAA-portlet\docroot\WEB-INF\service\z\service\FooService.java:23: error: package com.liferay.portal.kernel.service does not exist
    [javac] import com.liferay.portal.kernel.service.BaseService;
    [javac]                                         ^
    [javac] D:\LDS\lds\lsdk\portlets\AAA-portlet\docroot\WEB-INF\service\z\service\FooService.java:24: error: package com.liferay.portal.kernel.service does not exist
    [javac] import com.liferay.portal.kernel.service.InvokableService;
    [javac]                                         ^
    [javac] D:\LDS\lds\lsdk\portlets\AAA-portlet\docroot\WEB-INF\service\z\service\FooService.java:44: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac] public interface FooService extends BaseService, InvokableService {
    [javac]                                     ^
    [javac]   symbol: class BaseService
    [javac] D:\LDS\lds\lsdk\portlets\AAA-portlet\docroot\WEB-INF\service\z\service\FooService.java:44: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac] public interface FooService extends BaseService, InvokableService {
    [javac]                                                  ^
    [javac]   symbol: class InvokableService
    [javac] D:\LDS\lds\lsdk\portlets\AAA-portlet\docroot\WEB-INF\service\z\service\FooService.java:39: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac] @AccessControlled
    [javac]  ^
    [javac]   symbol: class AccessControlled
    [javac] D:\LDS\lds\lsdk\portlets\AAA-portlet\docroot\WEB-INF\service\z\service\FooServiceClp.java:19: error: package com.liferay.portal.kernel.service does not exist
    [javac] import com.liferay.portal.kernel.service.InvokableService;
    [javac]                                         ^
    [javac] D:\LDS\lds\lsdk\portlets\AAA-portlet\docroot\WEB-INF\service\z\service\FooServiceClp.java:27: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]     public FooServiceClp(InvokableService invokableService) {
    [javac]                          ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class InvokableService
    [javac]   location: class FooServiceClp
    [javac] D:\LDS\lds\lsdk\portlets\AAA-portlet\docroot\WEB-INF\service\z\service\FooServiceClp.java:65: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]     private InvokableService _invokableService;
    [javac]             ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class InvokableService
    [javac]   location: class FooServiceClp
    [javac] D:\LDS\lds\lsdk\portlets\AAA-portlet\docroot\WEB-INF\service\z\service\FooServiceUtil.java:20: error: package com.liferay.portal.kernel.service does not exist
    [javac] import com.liferay.portal.kernel.service.InvokableService;
    [javac]                                         ^
    [javac] D:\LDS\lds\lsdk\portlets\AAA-portlet\docroot\WEB-INF\service\z\service\FooServiceWrapper.java:19: error: package com.liferay.portal.kernel.service does not exist
    [javac] import com.liferay.portal.kernel.service.ServiceWrapper;
    [javac]                                         ^
    [javac] D:\LDS\lds\lsdk\portlets\AAA-portlet\docroot\WEB-INF\service\z\service\FooServiceWrapper.java:30: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]     ServiceWrapper {
    [javac]     ^
    [javac]   symbol: class ServiceWrapper
    [javac] D:\LDS\lds\lsdk\portlets\AAA-portlet\docroot\WEB-INF\service\z\service\persistence\FooPersistence.java:19: error: package com.liferay.portal.kernel.service.persistence does not exist
    [javac] import com.liferay.portal.kernel.service.persistence.BasePersistence;
    [javac]                                                     ^
    [javac] D:\LDS\lds\lsdk\portlets\AAA-portlet\docroot\WEB-INF\service\z\service\persistence\FooPersistence.java:38: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac] public interface FooPersistence extends BasePersistence {

```
[javac]                                                         ^
[javac] D:\LDS\lds\lsdk\portlets\AAA-portlet\docroot\WEB-INF\service\z\service\persistence\FooPersistence.java:260: error: type OrderByComparator does not take parameters
[javac]         com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.OrderByComparator<Foo> orderByComparator);
[javac]                                                         ^
[javac] D:\LDS\lds\lsdk\portlets\AAA-portlet\docroot\WEB-INF\service\z\service\persistence\FooUtil.java:21: error: package com.liferay.portal.kernel.service does not exist
[javac] import com.liferay.portal.kernel.service.ServiceContext;
[javac]                                         ^
[javac] Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
[javac] Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
[javac] 100 errors
```

BUILD FAILED
D:\LDS\lds\lsdk\build-common-plugin.xml:542: The following error occurred while executing this line:
D:\LDS\lds\lsdk\build-common.xml:985: Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details.

Total time: 16 seconds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You state that you're using the 7.0 SDK with liferay 6.2. Don't do that, use the matching version. 7.0 has quite a lot API updates that are incompatible with 6.2 and it seems that you're running into these.

However, it's hard to tell (or give more details) if all you post is the error message and not (a minimal version of) your code.